# Securely Transfer content of Uploaded file

Tags: php, security, upload, transfer

I am developing application using php mysql. The application will allow users (users will be from around 200 organisations) to upload excel data (CSV format) and the content will be inserted into the database. I am looking forward some methods to secure the content of the file during transfer. I seek your help.

Comment: Maybe you should look into SSL?

Answer (score 0):

[HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) will secure all communications between the web browser and the server. Only the source and destination will be visible to 3rd parties, everything else, including the URL path, will be encrypted.

> Hypertext Transfer Protocol Secure (HTTPS) is a communications protocol for secure communication over a computer network, with especially wide deployment on the Internet. Technically, it is not a protocol in and of itself; rather, it is the result of simply layering the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) on top of the SSL/TLS protocol, thus adding the security capabilities of SSL/TLS to standard HTTP communications.

Comment: is there any free tools for this?

Comment: You will need to buy an SSL certificate. You could generate your own for development and testing purposes, but this will cause a browser warning to be shown.